# The endpoints that are created with node.jsdoes not work properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a 2 different endpoint in index.js file. The android app calls and retrieves data with these endpoints from local MongoDB database. The first endpoint "/AddArac" works fine in starting but if ı Call "/AddArac" after calling "/ListArac" it gives an error.

For example:
/AddArac -  /ListArac  => this order is ok for both.
/ListArac  -  /AddArac  => this order is not ok for /AddArac.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var objectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

app.post('/AddArac', (request, response, next) => {
    mongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
    var db = client.db('basaranSMSDev');
    var data = request.body;
    var name = data.name;
    var plaka = data.plaka;
    var tel = data.tel;

    var json = { 'name': name, 'plaka': plaka, 'tel': tel };

    db.collection('Araclar').find({ 'plaka': plaka }).count(function (error, number) {

        if (number > 0) {
            response.json('Araç daha önce kaydedilmiş.');
        }
        else {
            db.collection('Araclar').insertOne(json, function (error, res) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json('Araç kaydında hata oluştu tekrar deneyiniz.');
                    console.log('Arac eklenemedi', err);
                }
                else {
                    res.json('Araç eklendi');
                    console.log('Arac eklendi.');

                }
            });

        }
        client.close();
    });
    
});

});




app.get('/ListArac', (req, res) => {
mongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
    var db = client.db('basaranSMSDev');
    var items = db.collection('Araclar').find().toArray();
    items.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        res.json(result)

    })
    console.log(items);
    client.close();

    });


})
```

The error:

> C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:106
> throw err;
> ^
> TypeError: res.json is not a function
> at C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\index.js:138:29
> at executeCallback (C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:70:5)
> at C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert_one.js:34:21
> at handleCallback (C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:102:55)
> at C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:269:5
> at C:\Users\Dilber\Basarannodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:405:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:75:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code

```
app.post('/AddArac', (request, response, next) => {
```

you have used `response` as the response parameter.
but you used `res` in

```
if (err) {
                    res.json('Araç kaydında hata oluştu tekrar deneyiniz.');
```

`res` is not a function in

`db.collection('Araclar').insertOne(json, function (error, res) {`